# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked - How to update template after Observable Value change

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-changedetection

I went through quite a lot of SO posts trying to find a solution to this one, the only one I found had a hack implementation. I have an observable taken from the ngrx store which I subscribe too:

```
this.navigationSelected$ = this.store.pipe(select(currentlySelectedNavigation));

this.navigationSelected$.subscribe(res => {
  ...
});
```

with an ngIf depending on this observable value inside of the template:

```
<profile-navigation *ngIf="(navigationSelected$ | async) == navigationLayout[0].location"></profile-navigation>
```

Whenever the value of navigationSelected$ changes, this throws:

```
ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ngIf: [object Object]'. Current value: 'ngIf: false'.
```

and the template does not update. I managed to go around it by running cdRef.detectChanges(); at the end of the subscription. It works fine but the error is still being thrown, plus as mentioned, it seems like a hack.

What would be the best way of achieving what I am trying to do?

Comment: If you have an explicit subscription to `navigationSelected$` inside the component, you can get rid of the async pipe altogether (have `*ngIf="someNewProperty"` instead, and compute `someNewProperty` inside the subscriber). If that won't solve the problem outright, maybe it'll help locating its source.

Comment: Thanks @mbojko I already tried that but the problem is not with the async pipe but the fact *ngIf value updates without triggering change detection so the component template doesn't re-render by default which leads to this error. As mentioned I added explicit change detection in the subscription which makes it work but the error is still there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Whenever the value of navigationSelected$ changes, this throws:

The error means that the value changed twice.

When you have these errors on a selector it can be very difficult to fix them. There isn't really anything wrong with the view. The problem is that the store is changing state before and after the view is rendered, and this likely means that there is a dispatch that should happen after a `setTimeout()` is called.

The problem is that this makes some other place in your source code dependent upon changing the state to protect the view from triggering the error. That's not ideal.

An alternative is to emit the value using `EventEmitter`.

```
<profile-navigation *ngIf="(navigationSelectedSafe$ | async) == navigationLayout[0].location"></profile-navigation>

public navigationSelectedSafe$ = new EventEmitter<any>(true); // must be true

this.navigationSelected$.subscribe(res => navigationSelectedSafe$.emit(res));
```

When you use `EventEmitter(true)` it will emit values after a `setTimeout()` which protects the view from change errors.

You can also *search* around your source code for places where you use `@Output()` and see if changing it to `EventEmitter(true)` fixes the problem.

Usually when you see this error on a selector. It means that you're doing a lot of state related work outside of the views. A component that needs to broadcast that something has changed should be using `@Output()` but if that component is dispatching, then it bypasses the view process. This is where you run into these issues.

Answer (score 7):

I usually add a debounceTime(0) to fix this issue.

this.navigationSelected$ = this.store.pipe(select(currentlySelectedNavigation), debounceTime());